# Import Windows AWS EC2 image into vmware using VMDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, vmware

I have to backup a windows server 2008 32bit I have on aws ec2, to my on premise vmware infrastructure. 
My objectif is to keep the .vmdk files aws provided me ( 2 disks ) and being able to restore the instance in my own infrastructure if needed.

I cannot use the aws ec2 create-instance-export-task because I have more than 1 disk, and do not match command requirements.

I have converted my ec2 to an AMI to use this command :
aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-id --disk-image-format VMDK

I had to follow this process to restore the .vmdk from the -flat.vmdk aws provided. 
https://www.settlersoman.com/how-to-recover-missing-vmx-and-vmdk-descriptor-file/

If I create a new VM with same CPU/Memory as my instance on AWS (t2.small), and then attach the .VMDK, i'm not able to make it boot. I tried with differents settings in vmware but nothing works.

I tried on VMWARE ESXI 6.0, VirtualBOx and vmware workstation.

Does anyone have a procedure to export a windows ec2 to an on premise hypervisor ( not using create-instance-export-task ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few years since I have done this, it is possible. I used this software: https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html

If I remember correctly I created an extra hard disk/volume, attached it to the ec2 instance and used that as the target to hold the VM the converter creates - then I uploaded the VM to S3 and pulled it down locally (and then got rid of that temporary volume). Worked like a charm.

BTW: The convertor software is free

Comment: Thank you, this tool is working fine. I was even able to directly output it in my vsphere server, and now I can boot the server.